# DaggerApplicationComponent not compiled

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, android-studio-3.0, dagger

I'm using the latest beta of android studio 3 (currently beta 4), and I can't seem to get it to generate the dagger classes needed.

From my side I created an empty project. Then I renamed the activity to match the dagger notes, YourActivity. See "Injecting Activity objects" in https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html, which shows this:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = ...)
public interface YourActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<YourActivity> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  public abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<YourActivity> {}
}

@Module(subcomponents = YourActivitySubcomponent.class)
abstract class YourActivityModule {
  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ActivityKey(YourActivity.class)
  abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>
  bindYourActivityInjectorFactory(YourActivitySubcomponent.Builder builder);
}

@Component(modules = {..., YourActivityModule.class})
interface YourApplicationComponent {}

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = { /* modules to install into the subcomponent */ })
abstract YourActivity contributeYourActivityInjector();

public class YourApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
  @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingActivityInjector;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    DaggerYourApplicationComponent.create()
        .inject(this);
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return dispatchingActivityInjector;
  }
}

//the renamed activity
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //added this line
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

I've also added the following from that page for the gradle build app file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11' // if you use the support libraries
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
}
```

because I was still not seeing anything I tried updating compile to implementation with still no luck, and if you're curious, that looks like:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11' // if you use the support libraries
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
}
```

Also, I've found the default setting where I can turn on the default `Build` -> `Compiler` -> `Annotation Processors` to Enable it. I did this before creating the new project.

After all of this, nothing seems to work. Is this broken in `android studio 3.x`? If not how did you get it work?

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahhh ha! I discovered the issue. It appears I needed another `annotationProcessor` line for the gradle app file

`annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'`

While their example doesn't quite work right, at least I am now seeing the `DaggerYourApplicationComponent`

the full gradle portion:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11' // if you use the support libraries
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

Note: I haven't tried replacing `compile` with `implementation`, but I'm just glad this worked.

Hopefully, this helps others too

Comment: This solved my problem as well, their example showed only the first 3 dependencies...adding this 4th resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Dagger like compile-time dependency injection tools need once run application. Then it will create automatically if there is no error.

Comment: When I try to build, each time it errors because it cannot find `DaggerYourApplicationComponent`. And if comment that code out then compile. It builds. After which I'll comment back in the `DaggerYourApplicationComponent` line to see it fail to find it and fail to build.

Comment: After cleaning project files my ApplicationComponent also deleting and giving error. But when all my providers and others are corrent , it will creating after first build

Comment: That's what I found too @mbakgun

Answer (score 3):

The detailed solution is here:

Inside your **app-level** `build.gradle` inside `dependencies` block, add these lines:

```
     //dagger2
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'

     compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
     implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Inside `android` block of **app-level** `build.gradle`,

```
kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
```

At the **top** of the **app-level** `build.gradle`, Do this in **exactly below order**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Finally, You need to configure Annotation Process as provided in the screenshot below. You can do this `File>Other Settings>Settings for New Projects>`search`"Annotation processor"`
[image]

After this, do from Menu `Build > Rebuild`. You are done!

**Test:**

```
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {

}
```

Now, you can use `DaggerApplicationComponent` that was generated at compile-time for your Applicati`o`nComponent interface.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it is too late. But `implementation` also work on dagger 2.11

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

I have made a simple hello world project to implement dagger 2.11 using Android Studio 3.0 beta-2. Hope this might help the beginners (like me) to have a good start since google documentation does not provide a clear instructions on it

[MyDaggerExample](https://github.com/charlesng/MyDaggerExample/tree/master)

Comment: Solved my problem after adding annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

Answer (score 1):

I started seeing problems when I upgraded to gradle 3.0.0 as well.  For me the solution was to change the implementation dagger lines to api:

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing  implementation & annotationProcessor to **kapt** might help you.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication?> {
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application?): Builder?
    fun build(): AppComponent?
    }
}
```

And from your application class

```
class BaseApplication : DaggerApplication() {
override fun applicationInjector(): AppComponent? {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this)?.build()
    //        return null;
   }

}
```

Also use change

```
implementation '*emphasized text*com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

to

```
kapt  'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
kapt  'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

Thank you.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Could you explain why kapt is working here?

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in gradle for dagger all 5 library given below

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
```

and also add repositories mavenCenteral()

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to the app level `build.gradle`

```
// dependency injection
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger2_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger2_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger2_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger2_version"
```

Answer (score -4):

You just need to run "Rebuild" of the project and fix all compile errors if any.